# Native Quarkus with AWS lambda does not build

Tags: java, aws-lambda, java-native-interface, alexa-skills-kit, quarkus

I am trying to use Quarkus native to build my AWS Lambda.

My setup is:

- GraalVM 19.3.0
- Java 11
- Ubuntu

When I run

```sh
docker run -v /home/mypc/dev/java/quarkus/alexa_swear/target/<my project>-1.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar:/project:z --user 1000:1000 --rm quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:19.2.1 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy\$BySpaceAndTime -jar <my project>-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -J-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:+AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:-JNI --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace <my project>-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
```

I get the following error:

```
[alexa_swear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:23]   (typeflow):  52,070.99 ms
[alexa_swear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:23]    (objects):  25,961.57 ms
[alexa_swear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:23]   (features):     803.41 ms
[alexa_swear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:23]     analysis:  81,015.48 ms
[alexa_swear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:23]     (clinit):   1,277.52 ms
[alexa_swear-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:23]     universe:   4,416.32 ms
Error: Unsupported features in 5 methods
Detailed message:
Call path from entry point to java.lang.Runtime.traceInstructions(boolean): 
    at java.lang.Runtime.traceInstructions(Runtime.java)
    at com.oracle.svm.reflect.Runtime_traceInstructions_91eaacf084b9d7e2af6dcc0028ee87fea9223b51_77.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.NTLMAuthenticationProxy.isTrustedSite(NTLMAuthenticationProxy.java:102)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getServerAuthentication(HttpURLConnection.java:2481)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1743)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AmazonLambdaRecorder$2.run(AmazonLambdaRecorder.java:171)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:460)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0) ... 6 more
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

The above error is truncated: the same call stack points to different unsupported methods, such as `java.lang.Thread.stop`.

My basic understanding is that`io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AmazonLambdaRecorder$2.run(AmazonLambdaRecorder.java` is referencing to some unsupported methods, such as `java.lang.Thread.resume()`. 
I have also tried with Quarkus 19.2.1 unsuccessfully.

The above command was executed by `mvn clean install -Pnative -Dnative-image.docker-build=true -e`.

Comment: I am not sure that this is a quarkus-problem. I would assume that it is a graalvm-problem. [The `LIMITATIONS`-page](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/LIMITATIONS.md#java-native-interface--jni) of graalvm lists JNI as "*mostly supported*" and also references the [configuration page for JNI on `substrateVM`](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/JNI.md). Maybe you want to take a look.

Comment: Thanks @Turing85, I will have a look at it.
P.S. Having given a look, it seems that threads are fully supported, but: `We have nearly full support for java.lang.Thread. Only deprecated methods, such as Thread.stop(), are not supported.`. So now I have to understand what references deprecated thread methods. I moved further somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Quarkus lambda extension?

Comment: @geoand thanks, yes I am using that. It does not happen with a blank project. Also, if I add the same dependencies on a blank project, it does not happen. Now I am proceeding by gradually removing parts of my code to see what causes the issue.
That is very time consuming, so any advice would greatly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the cause of my issue.

In the non-working version of my code, I use a factory of `com.amazon.ask.AlexaSkill` that is somehow injected in the entry point, as follows:

```
package io.mirko.lambda;

import com.amazon.ask.AlexaSkill;
import com.amazon.ask.Skills;
import com.amazon.ask.dispatcher.request.handler.HandlerInput;
import com.amazon.ask.dispatcher.request.handler.RequestHandler;
import com.amazon.ask.model.RequestEnvelope;
import com.amazon.ask.model.ResponseEnvelope;
import com.amazon.ask.request.interceptor.GenericRequestInterceptor;
import io.mirko.lambda.handlers.*;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;


public class SkillFactory {
    @Inject
    Instance<RequestHandler> handlers;

    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Named
    public AlexaSkill<RequestEnvelope, ResponseEnvelope> createSkill() {
        return Skills.standard()
                .addRequestHandlers(handlers.stream().toArray(RequestHandler[]::new))
                .addRequestInterceptor(new GenericRequestInterceptor<HandlerInput>() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(HandlerInput handlerInput) {
                        System.out.format("Processing %s\n", handlerInput.getRequest());
                    }
                })
                // Add your skill id below
                //.withSkillId("")
                .build();
    }
}

...

public class SwearStreamLambda extends SkillStreamHandler {
    @Named("swearStream")
        public SwearStreamLambda() {
            //noinspection unchecked
            super((AlexaSkill<RequestEnvelope, ResponseEnvelope>)
                getBean(new ParameterizedTypeImpl(AlexaSkill.class, RequestEnvelope.class, ResponseEnvelope.class)));
```

By removing the `SkillFactory` class and moving its logic inside `SwearStreamLambda` class the compilation went well.

Some notes:

1. The issue is not related to CDI, as it is heavily used throughout the project
2. The issue is not related to `@Produces` annotation, which is present in other parts of the project
3. The issue is not related to `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance`, as its removal does not solve the issue

All in all, I could not find the root cause of the problem, but I consider my issue *solved*.

P.S. The original problem is eradicated by building with the following:

`mvn clean install -Pnative -Dnative-image.docker-build=true -Dquarkus.native.enable-jni=true`

Please see `https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6395#issuecomment-570755587`.

This does not solve all the problems, as Quarkus reflection has to be configured, but it solves the specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just some update **for 2022**

- There is an extension in quarkus which do some configuration already for transitive dependencies: https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-amazon-alexa
- You need GraalVM and docker installed
- I just went to:
  https://code.quarkus.io/?b=GRADLE&e=io.quarkiverse.amazonalexa%3Aquarkus-amazon-alexa&extension-search=origin:platform%20alexa
- download the zip
- overwrite all of my existing project/skill.
- small further adaptions to my existing skill as described here: https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips
- `gradlew build -x test -Dquarkus.package.type=native  -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true`
- upload functions.zip to AWS Lambda

**Update 2023**

I used quarkus to get simplified GraalVM and native build support to speed up start lambda start times.
Nowadays I would first try [SnapStart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart.html) which is jsut a configuration in your lambda.